# Adding security details to a soap request in JAVA client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am building a Java client for a web service using WSDL URL. The WSDL for the web service doesn't mention any ws security details in it but I am told to include it in my request to the web service. 
I'm using AXIS2( WSDL2Java) to generate the client using WSDL URL.

Now how should I make it to work? Do I need to add/modify the auto generated client code to add custom methods to add security elements to Soap header?

**Is it possible to add security details to a soap request which is not available in WSDL?**

Comment: You should describe your authentication schema (a token appended to the URL, a HTTP header, a field in the SOAP header or envelope)

Comment: thanks for the reply.what if authentication schema is not given, is it possible to dd security headers using axis 2

Comment: You said "*I'm told to include security details in my request*", so whoever told you must have described how it works. The client must agree with the server to authenticate a request